# sdcard permission denied android

Tags: android, sd-card

I am trying to do method profiling for my application on Android 2.1 htc eris. It complains:

```
06-15 15:48:04.602: E/dalvikvm(826): Unable to open trace file '/sdcard/com.mayapp.trace': Permission denied
```

I have the following entry for user permission on my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

When I do adb push, I get the following error:

```
adb push AndroidManifest.xml a.txt
failed to copy 'AndroidManifest.xml' to 'a.txt': Read-only file system
```

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Does the app crash when you start it? I'm not exactly sure about this specific permission, but, usually, when I forget to add a permission to my manifest, a security exception is thrown. EDIT: Either way, the reading the data from the profiler using the DDMS tools is a part of ADB, not your app, so adding/not adding that permission wouldn't affect your ability of READING the file through ADB. I think your problems lie elsewhere. Make sure your sdcard is ok, test regular adb push/pull operations to see if file permissions are good, etc.

Comment: Nope, the app doesn't crash. But I am not able to get the Method Profiler to work.

Comment: (I edited my last comment with some more ideas)

Comment: @AlexRamallo Nice suggestion, I added my adb push output the question.

Comment: Have you checked if your code works on the emulator (vs. the actual device)?

Comment: Test that your sdcard is present and writeable, either using adb, or ddms file explorer, or by doing something like downloading a random pdf file with the browser.

Comment: The command you issued isn't writing to the SDCard but is probably writing to the root directory of your device. Try pushing to /sdcard/a.txt or /mnt/sdcard/a.txt. OR instead of pushing, try pulling, because that is what I would imagine that the profiler does when reading the trace file. If that fails, then you probably don't have read permissions to your sdcard

Comment: @AlexRamallo I tried adb push, it says it no content in sdcard. When I viewed through Astro File Manager I found that are some folders present in it. That means the sdcard is mounted with read/write permissions? DDMS filemanager shows no content inside the /sdcard

Comment: The could probably be with your ADB setup, and I can't really think of any solutions :(

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. It was informative, let me play with the adb and try to get something. I will post the solution when I resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a combination of badly placed sd card and read/write access to the sdcard. Used adb push/pull to verify the sd card and also used adb remount to change the access. that solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the answer but you could use

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

to access external sd card. My assumption is you wrote the directory yourself.

Comment: I don't require explicit access to the external storage. Method profiler complains that the permission is not available.